# Injecting EntityManager in servlet, it seems not thread safe

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, dependency-injection, entitymanager

I want to make a login app in Java EE. I thought of implementing it using a html page, a servlet and an entity class for the user, but it seems that `EntityManager` is not thread safe (can't be injected in the servlet and I need it to check the database) .

I read about `EntityManagerFactory` but I don't want to manage the life of the produced `EntityManager` when I can have the container do it. I think that some implementation using the DAO pattern could be made so that I can have an entity manager in the servlet, something like DAOImpl containing a manager, and have that class as a private variable in the servlet. But I couldn't find any useful tutorials online.

Could someone provide an implementation for this?

Comment: An object can only be not thread safe if it has mutable state.  So why not perform your authentication with a stateless object.  Isn't this the sort of thing that a @Stateless Session Bean is for (part of EJB 3.0)?

Comment: How exactly are you injecting it which made you think that it's not thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is to create a LoginService as @Stateless. It should contains the EntityManager. This EJB concern is manage login.

Now Inject the EJB into your servlet.

The container will take care about the concurrency.

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_in_an_ejb_injected

Comment: Also here: http://tamanmohamed.blogspot.cz/2012/03/jpa-thread-safety-when-injecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow Oracle suggested documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbrm.html) ,any approach should do : 
Either :

Injecting EntityManagerFactory in your dao impl via SerlvetContextListener.

```
 @PersistenceUnit        
 private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Or Injecting the EntityManager  in your DaoImpl.

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
```